# define variable name error in python what to do?

Tags: python

```
fig.ax = plt.subplots()
crimes_rape = crimes_total_2001['STATE'].values
y.pos = np.arrange(len(crimes_rape))
performance = crimes_total_2001['RAPE'].values
ax.barh(y.pos, performance, align = 'center', color = 'green', ecolor = 'black')
ax.set_ysticks(y,pos)
ax.set_ysticks(crimes_rape)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_xlabel('Rapes')
ax.set_title('RAPE VS STATE')
fig.set_size_inches(20,18,forward=True)
plt.show()
```

As I run the program in SPYDER, the variables [fig, ax] are giving an error of {undefined name}, I tried everything but the error still continues.
what to do?

Comment: put a comma in between `fig, ax` instead of full-stop/period.

Comment: So where did you define `fig`? `fig.ax` is not a single name; it's an expression that accesses the `ax` attribute of whatever object is bound to the name `fig`.

Comment: you're meant to create two variables there, that's why the comma.

Comment: This is more of a matplotlib question then a python question

Answer (score 1):

Where is "fig" defined?

If you never define fig....fig.ax =

will break

Same goes for "y" and "ax"

Try this...

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
crimes_rape = crimes_total_2001['STATE'].values
y = np.arrange(len(crimes_rape))
performance = crimes_total_2001['RAPE'].values
ax.barh(y, performance, align = 'center', color = 'green', 
ecolor = 'black')
ax.set_ysticks(y)
ax.set_ysticks(crimes_rape)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_xlabel('Rapes')
ax.set_title('RAPE VS STATE')
fig.set_size_inches(20,18,forward=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to unpack the matplotlib subplot. Like so:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```